# Young boy dreams of alien planet that's drying up and its princess

Tags: story-identification, novel

The novel centers around many characters, the main one is a young boy, who when he dreams can see into another planet. On this planet is a princess, a young alien girl who he states has features that are bony and angular, but still oddly beautiful. Her planet is out of water and is drying up. She begins to be able to see him. It has something to do with a chalice, grail, or cup of some kind.

An alien man falls into the an ocean on earth and is very tall, dark skinned, he learns English quickly and lives on the planet.

There is an old man who lives in the woods, and you find out he is a witch. He looks over the young boy and his mother.

There is an alien that is like a stick man that lives in the woods as well.

It was an odd book, but I loved it, and I think it is part of a trilogy and I want to complete reading them. If anyone knows what book this is I would be so happy!

Comment: Bueller? I'm still searching for this